# Evenly putting colored balls into bins

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

Given an array of $M$ bins and a set of colored balls. There are $n_i$ balls of color $i\in \cal{C}$ with $\cal C$ denoting the set of colors. $M$ is divisible by $n_i$ and $\sum_{i\in\cal{C}} n_i\le M$. The problem is to find a way of putting each ball into a bin such that the balls of a same color are evenly spaced. For example, if $M=4$, ${\cal{C}}=\{1,2\}$, and $n_1=n_2=2$, the solution is to put the two balls of the first color in bins $1$ and $3$ and the two balls of the second color in bins $2$ and $4$.

Comment: You mean that each bin should contain at most one ball, and the spacings between the balls of the same color are equal? In other words, you need disjoint arithmetic progressions of lengths $n_1,n_2\ldots,$ inside the set $\{1,2,\ldots,M\}$?

Comment: (Continued) if so, what is wrong with putting the balls of the first color to the first $n_1$ bins, the balls of the second color to next $n_2$ bins etc?

Comment: By evenly spaced, I require that the balls of the same color to be evenly distributed over the entire bin array, e.g., $M=9$ and $n_i=3$, a feasible configuration is to put the balls in bins $1,4,7$.

Comment: So the bins are in the vertices of a regular $n$-gon, and the progressions have differences $M/n_i$? Is this possible for $M=28$ and 14,7,4,2,1 balls of colors 1,2,3,4,5 respectively? I do not think so.

Comment: @FedorPetrov It doesn't seem so, indeed (an even simpler example is $M=6$ and $2,3$ balls of colors 1,2), but (in my understanding) what is being requested is a reasonably fast algorithm that either does it, or outputs "impossible" (if in the latter case it also produces something that is approximately fine, it will be a bonus). Of course, you can do a brute force search, but its running time is essentially $M^{|C|}$, which gets out of control very quickly. Still, it is just my understanding, so I'll let the OP clarify.